# ¿Problemas para solucionar error en Python: "NameError: name 'QtWidgets' is not defined" en PyQt5?

Tags: python, depuración

El error completo sería el siguiente:

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Projects\VB a Python\Ejercicio 2\descuentos.pyw", line 25, in <module>
    mi_app=Ventana()
  File "C:\Projects\VB a Python\Ejercicio 2\descuentos.pyw", line 7, in __init__
    QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
NameError: name 'QtWidgets' is not defined
>>> "
```

Por en cuanto al código, es el siguiente:

```
import sys
from descuentos import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class Ventana(QWidget):
 def __init__(self, parent=None):
  QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
  self.ui=Ui_Frm2()
  self.ui.setupUi(self)
  self.ui.BtnAceptar.clicked.connect(self.Aceptar)


def Aceptar(self):
    sueldo=self.ui.TxtSueldo.toPlainText()
    extra=self.ui.TxtExtra.toPlainText()
    sueldo=int(sueldo)
    extra=int(extra)
    neto= sueldo
    self.ui.TxtNeto.setText(str(neto))



if __name__== "__main__":
    mi_aplicacion=QApplication(sys.argv)
    mi_app=Ventana()
    mi_app.show()
    sys.exit(mi_aplicacion.exec_())
```

Ya lo he revisado un montón y sin embargo, no encuentro dónde está el error. Supongo que se encuentra dentro del primer bloque, pero ya lo he visto y reescrito varias veces y sigue sin efecto. :((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pasa porque no importas QtWidgets e intentas usar el `Namespace` en:

```
QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
```

Tu importas `QtWidget y` un montón de cosas más (todo los nombres de `PyQt5.QtWidgets`) usando wildcard en:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
```

pero no al propio `QtWidgets` en si. La solución sería cambiar la llamada al inicializador de la clase padre por:

```
QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
```

o mejor usa `super`:

```
super().__init__(parent)
```

Te recomiendo no usar wildcard para importar, es un mala práctico casi siempre porque es usado para lo que no se pensó, las razones son varias:

- Importas al espacio de nombres actual todos los nombres del espacio importado, muchos de ellos ni los vas a usar.
- Hace el código mucho menos legible al no conocer de forma explicita la procedencia de cada nombre. En Python la legibilidad cuenta y mucho.
- Permite el solapamiento de nombres entre espacios de nombres de forma inadvertida, ocasionando errores a veces silentes o difíciles de depurar.

La gente tiende a usarlo igual que el famoso `using naamespace std;` de C++ para ahorrarse unos caracteres al escribir. Esto no justifica su uso en absoluto, primero es más el tiempo que se pierde en depurar errores o leer el código que lo que se pierde en hacer referencia explícita al namespace en IDEs modernos con autocompletado. Además podemos usar alias (`import foooooooo as fo`) o importar un nombre de forma explícita con `from modulo import foo`.

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

import descuentos



class Ventana(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = descuentos.Ui_Frm2()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.BtnAceptar.clicked.connect(self.aceptar)


    def aceptar(self):
        sueldo = self.ui.TxtSueldo.toPlainText()
        extra = self.ui.TxtExtra.toPlainText()
        neto = int(sueldo) + int(extra)
        self.ui.TxtNeto.setText(str(neto))



if __name__ == "__main__":
    mi_aplicacion = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mi_app = Ventana()
    mi_app.show()
    sys.exit(mi_aplicacion.exec_())
```

Comment: ¡Sos lo máximo!